# Webpack 4. Set 'mode' option to 'development' or 'production' to enable defaults for this environment

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4, webpack-3

I have begin receive an error from webpack after update from webpack 3 to webpack 4 version -

`WARNING in configuration
The 'mode' option has not been set. Set 'mode' option to 'development' or 'production' to enable defaults for this environment.`

My current config is looks like below. What's I makes wrong?

```
config.globals = {
  'process.env': {
    NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(config.env)
  },
  NODE_ENV: config.env,
  __DEV__: config.env === 'development',
  __PROD__: config.env === 'production',
  __TEST__: config.env === 'test',
  __BASENAME__: JSON.stringify(process.env.BASENAME || '')
}
```

Comment: show all your webpack config, this is not your whole webpack config nor looks like one.

Comment: This is a warning, not an error, if you don't set `--mode` it will default to `production`